# Python program can't read new lines (enters)

Tags: python

So, I'm new to python, as you'll be able to tell, so if someone can, can you please explain it fully to me to learn? I really approciate any ideas in advance.
So basically, my python program is to count vowels in texts, but it can read like this **A B C** but can't read like this **A

B
C**
Here is my code to it:

```
def vowel_count(str): 

    count = 0

    vowel = set("aeiouőúűöóüáéíAEIOUŐÚŰÖÓÜÁÉÍ") 

    for alphabet in str: 

        if alphabet in vowel: 
            count = count + 1

    print("Vowel count : ", count)


str = input("Text :\n")

vowel_count(str)
```

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are having; are you trying to enter a multi-line string? `input` only reads up to the first newline. If you want multiple lines, you should read directly from `sys.stdin`.

Comment: May I recommend using `string` as your variable name rather than `str`.  Currently, you are renaming the built-in `str` data-type object, rendering it locally unusable.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you probably don't want to use [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) as a variable in Python as it is already being used as a "[built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html)".

I changed your code a little by adding some comments and print statements, hopefully it helps you understand what is going on:

```
def vowel_count(input_string):

    # using this to keep track of number of values found
    count = 0

    # removes duplicate values in string below
    vowel_string = set("aeiouőúűöóüáéíAEIOUŐÚŰÖÓÜÁÉÍ")

    # for each value in the input string
    for value in input_string:
        print(f"checking value:\t", value)
        if value in vowel_string:
            print(f"value in vowel_string?\tYes")
            # increase count by 1
            print("Adding 1 to count")
            count = count + 1
        else:
            print(f"value in vowel_string?\tNo")

        print(f"Count Total:\t{count}\n")

    print("Vowel count: ", count)

# ask the user to input some text and store it in variable str
# str = input("Text :\n")

# instead of asking for input, 
# create a string ahead of time
test_string1 = "aeiou"
vowel_count(test_string1)
# Output -> Vowel count :  5

test_string2 = "xfrt"
vowel_count(test_string2)
# Output -> Vowel count :  0
```

Comment: `str` is not a *reserved* word, it is just a built-in type.  Reserved words cannot be identifiers.  See [Keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)

Comment: Gotcha, I was trying to explain in simpler terms that he shouldn't be using str as a variable name because "built-In type" probably doesn't make much sense to a beginner.

Comment: Fair point of course, I only hope to help our language to be precise and consistent, for the benefit of all who may read these answers

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *alphabet* is a very bad word to choose, replace it with *letter* or *char* or something more meaningful. (all my personal opinion)

Second, print function implements a white space between its arguments itself, so you don't have to put a white space after semicolon in your print statement. (of course if you don't want two white spaces intentionally)

Third, don't use `str` as a variable name, because it is a built-in function which is used to convert other data types to string, if possible.

Now, about your problem, `input()` is a built-in function to read **one and only one line**. So, if you want to read multiple lines with `input()` function, you have to know total number of input lines and will need some sort of a loop like this;

```
text = ""
for line in range(lineNumber):
    text += input()
```

This way you will have `text` string, which is essentially all of your lines, combined.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and easy approach which uses [list comprehension](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3):

Basically, you're passing a string into the `vowel_count` function which loops through your defined vowels and counts the number of times that vowel occurs in the string.  These individual vowel counts (integers) are added to a `list`, which then is summed using the `sum()` function and assigned for return.

```
def vowel_count(text):
    vowels = sum([text.count(i) for i in 'aeiou'])
    return vowels

vowel_count('There are 11 vowels.\nHi, Im Bob - not really.')
```

#### Output:

```
11
```

Comment: after your comment on mine, I think I am allowed the say that, I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: I'll edit it in a second, however, again, I think what s/he is not able to do it is, to read inputs which are in form of `type "A", [press ENTER], type "B C" , [press ENTER]`. So, your solution assumes an input in form of a single string, probably is not gonna solve his/her problem if I am not wrong in my understanding of the question.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for you answers. What I was trying to do, is basically if I copy a poet for example, which has new and new lines, I can just paste it in and IF it is possible make the program read it. Thanks for you answeres and time!

Comment: Essentially, yes - this function will handle that.  If you save the poem to a plain text file (TXT for example) and read it into a variable with `with open('poem.txt', 'r') as f; text = f.read()`.  Then pass the `text` variable into `vowel_count` - in theory this should to what you're after.